# Getting typescript error in node and express project

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am working on a very simple book directory project . I have A JSON database file in my project and I am trying to simply make Get, POST, PATCH, and DELETE function. I got a TS7006 error in my UPDATE/PATCH function, here is the code snippet:

```js
change.patch('/update',jsonParser, (req, res) => {
    //get the username from url
    
    
    
    //get the update data
    const userData = req.body
    //get the existing user data
    const existUsers = getUserData()
    //check if the username exist or not       
    const findExist = existUsers.find(  name => existUsers.name === userData.name && existUsers.author===userData.author)
    if (!findExist) {
        return res.status(409).send({error: true, msg: 'username not exist'})
    }
    //filter the userdata
    const updateUser = existUsers.filter(name => userData.name !== existUsers.name )
    //push the updated data
    updateUser.push(userData)
    //finally save it
    saveUserData(updateUser)
    res.send({success: true, msg: 'User data updated successfully'})
})

const getUserData = () => {
    
    const jsonData = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../../database.json'));
    return(JSON.parse(jsonData));
    
}
```

I am getting an error on findExist where (name => existUsers.name === userData.name && existUsers.author===userData.author) name implicitly has any type error is coming.
Please help me here I am very new to typescript.

Comment: What's inside your database.json? An array of users?

Comment: yes , an array of name and author

Comment: Ok, take a look to [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) documentation. You are trying to compare `userData` with the array of users instead of each element.

Comment: I stringify the JSON object from getUserData(), but still get typescript error as the name implicitly has 'any' type error